# How to go to another activity and display the user details after google plus login in android app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I have successfully implemented the **Google plus** sign-in mechanism. But the user details are getting displayed in the same activity.

What I need is that, in one activity(**MainActivity.java**), I should have ***sign in button*** and after signing in, the user should be taken to another activity(**Home.java**) and display his ***profile photo, name*** etc.

How do i get user details in **Home.java**?

**MainActivity.java.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
public static final int AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE = 2000;


private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
TextView text;

String mAccountName;

private static final int REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 55664;
private static final String NAME_KEY = "given_name";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();


}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {

        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {

            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED && requestCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(mAccountName);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(mAccountName);


    getProfileInformation();


    updateUI(true);

}


private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
        super.onPostExecute(token);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Token Value: " + token);
        new GetAuthedUserName().execute(token);
    }
}

private class GetAuthedUserName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {   
            String token = params[0];
            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="
                    + token);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int serverCode = con.getResponseCode();
            //successful query
            if (serverCode == 200) {
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                String name = getFirstName(readResponse(is));
                MainActivity.this.show("Hello " + name + "!");
                is.close();


            } else if (serverCode == 401) {
                GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(MainActivity.this, token);
                onError("Server auth error, please try again.", null);
                Log.e(TAG, "Server auth error: " + readResponse(con.getErrorStream()));

            } else {
                Log.e("Server returned the following error code: " + serverCode, null);

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return "error - Malformed URL " + e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "error - IO error " + e;
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }


}

protected void onError(String msg, Exception e) {
    if (e != null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
    }
    MainActivity.this.show(msg); 
}

private static String readResponse(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0) {
        bos.write(data, 0, len);
    }
    return new String(bos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
}

public void show(final String message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG,message);
        }
    });
}

private String getFirstName(String jsonResponse) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    return profile.getString(NAME_KEY);
  }

public String getProfileInformation() {

    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateUI(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_sign_in:           

        new signInAsyc().execute();

        break;
    case R.id.btn_sign_out:

        signOutFromGplus();

        break;

    }
}

private class signInAsyc extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute()
    {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Signing in...");          
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {             
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        pd.dismiss();
    }     

}

private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }
}


private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

}
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

}

}
```

Let me know your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this answer is not gonna be late.Had similar issue and my workaround was to use a ViewFlipper that contains two layouts.One  layout for the login and the main layout as below

```
      <ViewFlipper android:id = "@+id/main_flipper"
       android:layout_width = "match_parent"
       android:layout_height = "match_parent>

       <include layout ="@layout/login_layout"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height ="match_parent"/>

       <include layout = "@layout/main_layout"
         android:layout_height ="match_parent"
         android:layout_width = "match_parent"/>
     </ViewFlipper>
```

Then in your main activity retrieve the flipper

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
           private ViewFlipper mMainFlipper;

           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           mMainFlipper =(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.main_flipper);

          if(/**your login logic is not satisfied**/)
          {
            mMainFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0)
          }else if(/** If your login logic is satisfied and the user is successfully                    logged in**/)
        {
         mMainFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
         }
```

}

Now, for some unknown reasons ViewFlipper crashes at times on some devices.So you could create a SafeViewFlipper as thus:

```
    public class SafeViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {

public SafeViewFlipper(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public SafeViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public SafeViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    try {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        stopFlipping();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

Might not be the best approach,but I guess it's a workaround.Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create parcelable object with needed fields, put it in intent extra
and start activity you need, then just obtain that object in new activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences, it would be the best way.